# VueCompilerError: Illegal tag name. Use '&lt;' to print '<'

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, laravel-mix

I am migrating a Vue 2 app to Vue 3, and using vue@3.2.36 with vue/compat@3.3.2 with compatConfig MODE=2.

The following error appear.

```
ERROR in ./resources/src/views/app/pages/transfers/edit_transfer.vue?vue&type=template&id=09285268 (./node_modules/laravel-mix/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[3]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??clonedRuleSet-30!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[1].rules[54].use[0]!./resources/src/views/app/pages/transfers/edit_transfer.vue?vue&type=template&id=09285268)
Module Error (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js):

VueCompilerError: Illegal tag name. Use '&lt;' to print '<'.
at /Users/resources/src/views/app/pages/transfers/edit_transfer.vue:721:66
376|                        v-model.number="detail.tax_percent"
377|                        :state="getValidationState(validationContext)"
378|                        aria-describedby="OrderTax-feedback"
   |                                           ^
379|                      ></b-form-input>
380|                    </b-input-group>
SyntaxError: 
VueCompilerError: Illegal tag name. Use '&lt;' to print '<'.
at /Users/resources/src/views/app/pages/transfers/edit_transfer.vue:721:66
376|                        v-model.number="detail.tax_percent"
377|                        :state="getValidationState(validationContext)"
378|                        aria-describedby="OrderTax-feedback"
   |                                           ^
379|                      ></b-form-input>
380|                    </b-input-group>
```

please help how to clean this project. thank you

Comment: Show us the full component template.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!-- Tax Rate -->
        <b-col lg="12" md="12" sm="12">
          <Field
            name="Order Tax"
            :rules="{ required: true , regex: /^\d*\.?\d*$/}"
            v-slot="validationContext"
          >
            <b-form-group :label="$t('OrderTax') + ' ' + '*'">
              <b-input-group append="%">
                <b-form-input
                  label="Order Tax"
                  v-model.number="detail.tax_percent"
                  :state="getValidationState(validationContext)"
                  aria-describedby="OrderTax-feedback"
                ></b-form-input>
              </b-input-group>
              <b-form-invalid-feedback id="OrderTax-feedback">{{ validationContext.errors[0] }}</b-form-invalid-feedback>
            </b-form-group>
          </Field>
        </b-col>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Convert the `rules` value to computed property.